# How to prevent Visual Studio 2019 from formatting CSS as multi-line on paste?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2019

I like to format my CSS as a single line per selector. When I'm hand-coding, that's easy enough in VS 2019. But, as soon as I paste something it expands the following attributes onto 1 line per attribute. I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to get it back to one line, but I'd prefer it didn't expand when pasting at all. I'm constantly fighting the autoformatting. Is it possible to turn this off? I've played with all of the options settings I can think of. Does anyone know how to turn off the autoformatting when pasting CSS in VS 2019?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by going to the **Tools** menu and selecting **Options**.

In the **Options** window, go to Text Editor > CSS > Advanced and set "Format on paste" to **Off**:

[image: VS Options window on CSS' Advanced section]

Here is an animated gif showing that changing this setting solves this problem:

[image]

Comment: Already have that set to off.  Still attempts to autoformat anytime I paste in the CSS editor.

Comment: @s15199d Then you are almost surely copying something from a site that has hidden new line characters in its markup. I had this set to on, wrote several CSS properties in one line on JSFiddle, copied to VS2019, and it auto formatted to one property per line. When I changed this to Off, re-copied the same line from JSFiddle and re-pasted to VS2019, it didn't auto format, and left it as one line.

Comment: @s15199d I've added a gif to the answer that shows this working.

Comment: Figured it out.  I had the auto format on paste turned off on CSS.  I was actually working in an SCSS file.  I had to turn off the same switch for SCSS.  Thanks for your help!